# Can't run java 8 update 60 in IE 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11, mozilla

I use the last Java 8 update 60, and use Mozilla and Internet Explorer 11 browsers. In both browsers when I verify browser version it reports back 8 update 60 to me.

But in my web Application when I click on button in Mozilla I get a security warning to run it, and in IE 11 nothing happens at all. I tried to turn on popups and other, but nothing seems to help.

[First dialog of the security warning](http://prntscr.com/8bcwtq)

[Second dialog of the security warning](http://prntscr.com/8bcxbx)

Comment: You should try: enabling the plugin in IE, ensuring your JRE security is set to medium and the path to your host:port is added to the security settings, ensuring the applets are signed with valid certificates, etc. Or just don't run applets and enjoy life.

Comment: where I can find path to my host:port and certificates?

Comment: You can use self-signed certificates if you don't want to pay a CA. The host and port are the host and port of the web application you're connecting to that serves applets. E.g. http://localhost:8080 if you were running a local server on Tomcat with default settings...

Comment: are you referring to applets? or the web server ssl certificates?

Comment: First this: http://prntscr.com/8bcwtq

Comment: And after press a button I have this http://prntscr.com/8bcxbx